# How to set up multiple levels of authentication in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want to set up a web application with two levels of authentication. The first level should be a password prompt. After you have authenticated via the first level you would have to select your name from a list which would log you in as that user. When you logout it should take you back to the user selection screen and you shouldn't have to re-type the password.

How can I achieve this with ASP.NET Core and Identity? I'm wanting to use this to set up a local intranet at my home but host it publicly so I can access it anywhere (hence the first level of password authentication before you can select a user).

Comment: That's not *two* levels of authentication. There's only one level, followed by *impersonating* another user. At least, that's the only case where it would make sense for one username/password combination to have access to multiple user accounts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the password would be static (the same for all users). I just want some level of security before the "User selection" screen is available.

Comment: In that case there is no authentication at all - no security whatsoever. Don't do that. You might as well remove ASP.NET Identity altogether. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: `but host it publicly so I can access it anywhere` that's *exactly* how networked home printers, routers and IoT devices get compromised and used in DDoS attacks. That's why printer companies like HP *disabled* smart features on their printers, like apps and internet-facing UIs. This is a case where you want *more* security, not less.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you are misunderstanding the concept. I am trying to build an app where members of my family can login by selecting their name from a list, but obviously I don't want anyone to be able to do this. So I need some way to authenticate access to the site before you can select a user to login as.

Comment: In fact, ASP.NET Core comes with out-of-the-box support for 2FA apps like Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator. It's probably *easier* to create a secure site than the insecure list of users. There's even an article that shows [how to generate QR Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to make the use of authenticator apps even easier

Comment: I didn't misunderstand the concept. What you try to do is no different than any web cam, IoT fridge or coffee maker with a single password. I'm saying if this gets on the public internet it will be compromised within hours, the same as those IoT devices would be compromised.

Comment: In any case, what you ask is no different than normal authentication with a single account and a dropdown to select a `UserID` to carry around. You don't need another level of authentication, just store that ID in a session variable

Comment: [This method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_SignInAsync__0_System_Boolean_System_String_) might allow you to sign in without a password (you'll need to try it). But as others have noted just having each member of the family have their own password would be easier

Comment: Thanks @Richard, I will take a look. The reason I don't want users to have to type a password every time is that I want to have a tablet on the wall in my home where any family member can quickly select their name to log in and access the site

Comment: Why not just host multiple instances. You can deploy one internally with no authentication required, and deploy one externally with full security. They can both connect to the same backend (database, etc.). They can both even be the same codebase. You can treat it like environments and then conditionally enable authentication for the "external" environment.